# How to convert date column from dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy/mm/dd in a .CSV file

Tags: linux, date, csv, sed, awk

I have a .CSV file with about 15 fields in the file and I need to convert the date column(the first field in the file) from dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy/mm/dd. Please advise...

Comment: awk together with split() does the job. Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: I am just starting with learning the basics, not much familiar with all the commands, however, I tried to use the below

> echo "dd-mm-yyyy" | awk 'BEGIN{FS="-";OFS="-"}{print $3,$2,$1}'

However, I tried only to convert 1 date given at prompt, was wondering how we do this if there are multiple columns in a .CSV file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using awk
This splits `$1` to three parts and join them back to new `$1`, then print all `1`

```
echo "30/05/2013 some data" | awk '{split($1,a,"/");$1=a[3]"/"a[2]"/"a[1]}1'
2013/05/30 some data
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i -r 's|(..)/(..)/(....)|\3/\2/\1|' file
```